# Is it possible to have Joom!Fish point one item to another rather than translating its contents?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomfish

I have three items that are not simply translated based on the language but also have different content. What I would like to do is the following:

1. User comes to the aforementioned item.
2. User changes the language.
3. User is presented with another item, that is appropriate for the chosen language.

All I can do now at step 3 is present the user with the same item but have it's contents translated.

I can accomplish this by doing some "hacking", however, I would like to know if anyone knows a **proper Joom!Fish way** to do this or not?

Thanks!

Comment: when you say "User is presented with another item", do you mean a completely different article?

Comment: Yes, exactly! An article with entirely different content.

Comment: By default Joomfish! is made to translate everything, i.e. each site is a mirror but in a different language. But there are some premium plugins available from them to modify this - like the Multilingual Menu Addon plugin (have different menus per language). maybe that would help? It wouldn't change the content of the article immediately but it would allow you to have a menu item to a different article if they click on a new language. They also have an Extended Router plugin. Would probably be best to ask them if that would help.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't achieve this with JoomFish, as its designed to show translated content. Im not sure why you would want different articles on a website for different languages.

Comment: @Trev I'll look for these plugins, thanks!